# AWS will charge for public IPv4 addresses: how can I reduce costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ipv4, cost-management, aws-cost-explorer

AWS has announced that it will charge **$0.005 per hour per public IPv4 address** starting February 2024. Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/

I've researched ways to mitigate these costs and read various documentations, but I would like to hear from the active community to better understand this issue.

In my research, I found an alternative approach involving a **public/private VPC setup where internet access occurs through a NAT Gateway**. This would eliminate the need for multiple public IPv4 addresses, keeping only one to be paid for. However, using the NAT Gateway would incur its own costs and might not be worthwhile for a small architecture.

**My architecture** is based on three applications in Elastic Beanstalk, each with its instance having a public IPv4 for clients to access the platform through a browser. Another public IPv4 is allocated to the RDS MySQL.

This will result in a cost of $0.005/hour/public IPv4 → 0.005 * 24 * 31 * 4 = **$14.88**.

Meanwhile, using a public/private VPC with NAT Gateway would incur costs like:

- NAT Gateway hourly charges: $0.045/hour/NAT Gateway x 730 hours x 1 NAT Gateway = $32.85/month
- NAT Gateway data processing fees: $0.045/GB x 10 GB (assuming 10 GB traffic) = $0.45/month
- Public IPv4 address charges in use: $0.005/IP/hour x 730 hours x 1 Elastic IP = $3.65/month
- Therefore, US$ 32.85 + US$ 0.45 + US$ 3.65 = US$ 36.95

My question is whether it's possible to mitigate the cost of the public IPv4. Can anyone provide guidance?

Comment: Each of your Beanstalk apps is independently reachable from outside via its unique public IP address, presumably. I don't see how NAT Gateway will help you there.

Comment: AT 0.005 / hr / ip, a public IPv4 is still the most cost effective way to build the network you describe.  If you want to offset the additional costs, Id look elsewhere (rightsizing ec2 or rds instance(s) or moving to fargate / lambda if the services don't run very hot).

Comment: I don't know any better solutions than what nickdoesstuff mentioned if sticking to only AWS services.

However, if you already happen to use Cloudflare's DNS service, you can  use their proxy functionality to proxy IPv4 traffic to your IPv6 instances at no cost, removing the need for any public IPv4 adresses in AWS. That is definitely not an option for everyone, but a very useful property if you already happen to be a (free or paying) customer.

Answer (score 3):

NAT Gateway can only be used for outbound access.

With Elastic Beanstalk your flows are ingressing into your apps, so NAT Gateway is of no help there.

You can associate Beanstalk apps with a VPC to expose them on private IPs and then front them with Application Load Balancer (ALB) or a Virtual Appliance like Aviatrix Gateway to use one public IP for multiple EB applications.